# Function called over and over again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I've got a `Pagination` component in NextJS which looks like:

```
import Pagination from 'react-bootstrap/Pagination';
import Router from "next/router";
import {useEffect} from "react";

export { Paging }

function Paging(props) {

    let pages = []

    const generatePages = () => {
        for (let page = 1; page <= props.paginator.totalPages; page++) {
            let url = `/${props.source}?page=${page}&per_page=${props.paginator.perPage}`
            console.log(url)
            pages.push(
                <Pagination.Item key={page} active={page == props.paginator.page } onClick={() => Router.push(url)}>
                    { page }
                </Pagination.Item>
            );
        }
    }

    generatePages();

    return (
        <div id="pagination">
            <div className={"pagination-component"}>
            <Pagination>
                { props.paginator.prevPage != null &&
                    <Pagination.Prev onClick={() => Router.push(props.paginator.prevPage)} />
                }

                { pages }

                { props.paginator.nextPage != null &&
                    <Pagination.Next onClick={() => Router.push(props.paginator.nextPage)}/>
                }
            </Pagination>
            </div>
            <div className={"total-pages"}>
                Showing {props.paginator.perPage} out of { props.paginator.totalCount }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

this works fine. The pagination is rendered and working as expected:

[image: Pagination]

but when I open the web inspector I see that this statement `console.log(url)` which is declared in the `generatePages` function is printed over and over again, which leads me to think that my component is being rendered over and over again.

I added then:

```
useEffect(() => {
        generatePages();
    }, []);
```

and removed the call to `generatePages();` that I had before the return statement. That stoped the message printing from appearing multiple times but now the pages on my component are not being displayed:

[image: component not rendered correctly]

I tried passing `pages` array as dependency to `useEffect` but that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas what's going on?

**EDIT**

For debugging purposes I've completely removed `generatePages` and updated my `return` value to be:

```
return (
        <div id="pagination">
            <div className={"pagination-component"}>
            <Pagination>
                { props.paginator.prevPage != null &&
                    <Pagination.Prev onClick={() => Router.push(props.paginator.prevPage)} />
                }

            { console.log('here') }

                { props.paginator.nextPage != null &&
                    <Pagination.Next onClick={() => Router.push(props.paginator.nextPage)}/>
                }
            </Pagination>
            </div>
            <div className={"total-pages"}>
                Showing {props.paginator.perPage} out of { props.paginator.totalCount }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

as you can see I'm just creating the component with whatever data is passed via `props` and added `{ console.log('here') }` to the return to see whether the component was being rendered multiple times from the parent component.
That seems to be the case. I was expecting to see `here` printed only once but it's being printed infinitely.

The parent component where `Paging` is being used is:

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { HiOutlineTrash, HiOutlinePencil } from "react-icons/hi";
import { getAllGenres } from "../../api/genre";
import Link from 'next/link'
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import useStore from "../../stores";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";
import { Paging } from "../../components/Pagination";

export default function Genres({ genres, pagination }) {

    const alerts = useStore((state) => state.alerts)
    const removeAllAlerts = useStore((state) => state.removeAllAlerts);

    const setShow = (show=false) => {
        removeAllAlerts();
    }

    // automatically close any open alerts after 10 seconds
    (() => setTimeout(setShow, 10000))();

    return (
        <>
            { alerts.length > 0 &&
            <Alert variant="success" onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
                <p>
                    { alerts[0] }
                </p>
            </Alert>
            }

            <div className={"page-title-section"}>
                <h2 className={"page-title"}>Genres</h2>
                <div className={"add-new-top"}>
                    <Link href={"/genres/new"}>
                        <Button variant="dark">Add New Genre</Button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Parent</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Created At</th>
                    <th/>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                { genres.data && genres.data.map(genre => (
                    <tr key={genre.id}>
                        <td>
                            <Link href={`/genres/${genre.slug}`}>
                                { genre.name }
                            </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>{ genre.description }</td>
                        <td>{ genre.parent }</td>
                        <td>{ genre.active ? "Yes" : "No" }</td>
                        <td>{ genre['created_at'] }</td>
                        <td>
                            <Link href={"/"}>
                                <a className={"action-btn edit-btn"}><HiOutlinePencil /></a>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href={"/"}>
                                <a className={"action-btn remove-btn"}><HiOutlineTrash /></a>
                            </Link>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>

            <Paging paginator={pagination} source={"genres"} />
        </>
    )
}

/**
 * getServerSideProps gets all server side data before the page actually loads
 * @returns {Promise<{props: {genres: void}}>}
 */
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {

    // extract from query params in context data needed for pagination
    const page = context.query.page;
    const perPage = context.query.perPage;

    let genres = {}
    const res = await getAllGenres(page, perPage);

    if (res.data !== undefined) {
        genres = res.data
    }

    // build pagination object
    let pagination = {
        totalPages: res.data["total_pages"],
        totalCount: res.data["total_count"],
        perPage: res.data["per_page"],
        page: res.data["page"],
        nextPage: res.data["next_page_link"],
        prevPage: res.data["prev_page_link"],
    }

    return {
        props: {
            genres,
            pagination,
        }
    };
};
```

it is just a simple table with the `Paging` component, but I can't figure out what's causing the multiple rendering of `Paging`.

But it's confusing me a lot at the moment is that I'm getting two sets of results: On one hand I've got the output in Chrome Dev Tools which keeps printing the message over and over:

[image: chrome dev tools]

on the other I've got my terminal open, which is also printing the message, but it only prints it twice:

[image: terminal output]

which one is correct?

Comment: In first scenario, console.log is printing constantly without clicking on pagination? Or does it print only after  user action?

Comment: You're using mutable "state" and then (with useEffect) updating it after the component first renders without any signal that it now needs to be re-rendered.

Comment: @CptSosen it's printing constantly without clicking on pagination

Comment: @jonrsharpe not following. If I were to use `pages` as dependency to `useEffect` I'd be indicating signaling that any change in `pages` should trigger a re-rendering, and that re-rendering is executed by `generatePages`. Isn't that right?

Comment: `pages` is _never_ changed, as far as React knows, because arrays are compared by _identity_. That's why you avoid mutating things.

Comment: You sould use useEffect and in dependency array try to include pages and props.paginator

Comment: @CptSosen I just tried that. Pages still missing, same results as working with `[]` as dependency

Comment: `console.log(url)` will be logged over and over again because its in a loop, or is it rendering more than the page count (if it's more than the page count, is it 2 times the amount, or does it just continue to log infinitely)? When a component rerenders, it executes your function body, causing `generatePages` to be called multiple times. A component only rerenders if you update its state (which you're not doing), or the parent component that is using `<Paging />` is rerendering multiple times.

Comment: it prints more than the pages count. My current number of pages is 2 but the statement is constantly being printed, never stops.

Comment: so shall set `pages` to use `useState` and pass it to `useEffect` as dependency?

Comment: Storing JSX in state isn’t often not recommended. Your better off trying to find the source of why your component is infinitely rerendering. Does putting a log before `let pages` also infinitely log? Does removing all code from within your component and retuning some JSX that shows text also indirect log if you log before the return? You can try some things to debug

Comment: @NickParsons I updated the question. As I see it now I believe the issue might be related to the parent component re-rendering the child component (`Paging`) multiple time, but haven't figured out why this is happening

Comment: I recommend you to reproduce this on some online codespace (eg codesandbox.io/stackblitz).

Comment: What is `removeAllAlerts` doing? Is it modifying state within your store? It would be good if you do as bogdanoff suggested an add a [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the dependency array completely so there is no second argument to the `useEffect`

Comment: Had tried that as well, the result wasn't any different as with the array as second argument

Comment: This won't help because it's still mutating the array _after_ it's rendered while empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should store `pages` in state and only call `generatePages` on mount.